# shared library searching for patterned names

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I've opened a shread library with `lt_dlopen` and would like to search the list of exported symbols for those matching a specific pattern (the name of the function matches the pattern).

Is there any simple way to do this? Either search by pattern, or just get a list of all exported named. By simple I mean without a special library just for loading symbols.

The main program and library is C++ but all symbols will be `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the recipe outlined [in this article](http://linuxgazette.net/issue85/misc/sandeep/Ptrace.c.txt) just that, if you're accessing symbols within our own address space / from a library you loaded via `dlopen()` is much simpler:

1. The "struct link_map*" you obtain by `reinterpret_cast<struct link_map*>(dlopen(...));` - so no need to parse "your own ELF". See the [sourcecode for `__dlopen()`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=dlfcn/dlopen.c;hb=HEAD).
2. You don't need to use `ptrace()` to read from your own address space - just cast the pointers directly.

I'll illustrate the 2nd for finding the symbol table address:

```
struct link_map *map = reinterpret_cast<struct link_map*>(dlopen(...));
int nchains = 0;
Elf32_Dyn *dyn = static_cast<Elf32_Dyn*>(map->l_ld);
Elf32_Sym *symtab = NULL;
char *strtab = NULL;

while (dyn->d_tag) {
    switch (dyn->d_tag) {
    case DT_HASH:
        nchains = *static_cast<int*>(dyn->d_un.d_ptr + map->l_addr + 4);
        break;
    case DT_SYM:
        symtab = static_cast<Elf32_Sym*>(dyn->d_un.d_ptr);
        break;
    case DT_STR:
        strtab = static_cast<char*>(dyn->d_un.d_ptr);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    dyn++;
}
```

This is an in-memory equivalent of the `resolv_tables()` function in the article I linked to. Converting the `find_sym_in_tables()` to a pattern-search through your own address space is left as an exercise to the reader.

Note that this is Linux-specific (`dlopen()` returning a `struct link_map*`). For other systems, the technique should work as long as this condition is met (and they're using ELF).

**Edit:** This is for 32bit ELF; if you're using 64bit, data types change (`Elf64_Sym` / `Elf64_Dyn` and 64bit integers for the table size I think). I'm sure this can be abstracted (the glibc sources do so ...), it just doesn't make the code easy to read anymore. Again, I leave it as exercise to the reader.